# Symfony2 global and optional locale detection from route

Tags: url-routing, locale, symfony-2.1

Here's what I want to achieve, followed by a compilation of the knowledge I acquired, with no solution.

In a Symfony2 project, **without using a dedicated bundle**, I want the first directory in path to define the locale. It must be optional:

- **1.** http://www.example.com/user/account => default *EN* locale, *user* bundle, *account* controller, default *index* action.
- **2.** http://www.example.com/fr/user/account => forced *FR* locale...
- **3.** http://www.example.com/en/user/account => forced *EN* locale (needed option even though EN is the default locale)

As I will have over 100 routes at the end of the project, and considering that locales can be added any time, **i need all the locale routing to be written only once**.

No chance to achieve that with one routing file. An interesting solution from SF2.1 was the chained routing files, explained by Fabien Potencier himself: one file prefixes the locales and chains to the normal routing. Here we are:

The first file, lists non-locale-aware routes and chains to the locale-aware routing file for all other, normal routes.

-- *routing.yml:*

```
sys_ajax:
  resource: "@SystemAjax/InternalAjax/get"
  prefix:   /sysajax

locale_routing:
  resource: base_routing.yml
  prefix: /{_locale}
  defaults:
    _locale: fr
```

-- *base_routing.yml:*

```
user:
  resource: "@UserBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
  prefix:   /user
```

*@BTUserBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml* is a normal bundle routing file.

Ok, so that works for URLs with locale in path (examples 2 and 3), but no route is found if i remove the optional locale part (example 1). It's easy to guess that the problem comes from the {_locale} token capturing the "user" part of the URL as a locale when there is no locale string in URL. But then how can i tell it to let the URL untouch and chain it to the next file if the first part of the URL is not en|fr|it|de for example?

A solution from a forum was to make 2 routes:

-- *routing.yml:*

```
sys_ajax:
  resource: "@SystemAjax/InternalAjax/get"
  prefix:   /sysajax

locale_routing:
  resource: base_routing.yml
  prefix: /{_locale}
  requirements:
    _locale: fr|en

locale_routing2:
  resource: base_routing.yml
  prefix: /
  defaults:
    _locale: fr
```

One rule has the locale part, one has not. Unfortunately that doesn't work because there's twice the line `resource: base_routing.yml` (one for each rule), the later overriding the former.

Here i am, no good solution...

I love Symfony (since 2008) but sometimes I'm just amazed how simple problems can require very complex solution with this framework.

Comment: Regardless that having multiple urls with the same content is bad for SEO, i'm interested in this question too :)

Comment: I'm also looking for a solution to this problem and can't believe no one has come up with anything so far.

Answer (score -1):

You could always tackle it from the other direction and use a decent editor with macros to write the routing files. Hardly any manual labor and you will achieve what you want. Modifying it will be simple with regex replace and/or a macro.

Comment: Well, of course... but that's not the deep purpose of my original post. I wrote it as much for problem you can read as for mentionning the general complexity i sometimes encounter in this wonderful framework. A routing mechanism that does not handle such an obvious locale mechanism needs improvement, in my humble opinion.

Comment: Oh, I agree 100% that it makes very simple things very complicated at times. Such is the world of Java. Did I say Java? I meant Symfony2 :)