# Symfony route: Optional locale directory in class prefix annotation

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I need to be able to define routes where the `/{_locale}` part is optional. This means I need these URLs to use the same controller:

1. `my-domain.com/` (the locale will be set by a request listener)
2. `my-domain.com/[any-locale]/`

Same goes with:

3. `my-domain.com/my-page` (the locale will be set by a request listener)
4. `my-domain.com/[any-locale]/my-page`

The problem is I can't define two class `@Route` annotations as this isn't valid/accepted by Symfony; and I can't duplicate each and every route in my controller classes because there will be a large number and that would be really bad!

I've tried having only one class annotation but I couldn't get it to work. Here are my attempts:

## First:

```
/**
 * @Route("/{_locale}", requirements={"_locale": "(\w{2,3})?"})
 */
class DefaultController extends Controller {

    /**
     * @Route("/")
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request) {
        return new Response('index '.$request->getLocale());
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/my-page")
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function testAction(Request $request) {
        return new Response('test '.$request->getLocale());
    }

}
```

Conclusions:

1. Works
2. Works
3. Fails (because only `my-domain.com//my-page` would work)
4. Works

## Second:

I thought the problem was the leading slash, so i tried this:

```
/**
 * @Route("{slash_and_locale}", requirements={"slash_and_locale": "\/?(\w{2,3})?"}, defaults={"slash_and_locale": ""})
 */
class DefaultController extends Controller { // ...
```

Conclusions:

1. Works
2. Works
3. Fails (same reason)
4. Works

I've seen this [(old) question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13358873/282695) but no proper answer has been submitted yet :(

Anyone with a suggestion?
Would be really helpful, thanks!

Comment: Use this bundle https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle

Comment: Not sure this bundle does that exactly but I will try to see if it is customizable the way I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I eventually decided to do:

1. despite what I wanted, I define two routes for each controller action (see example below);
2. I extend Symfony's `RoutingExtension` to automatically pick the correct route when using `path` or `url` methods.

Here's what my double route configuration looks like (note the double route, the second having a `+locale` suffix):

```
<?php

// src\AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class DefaultController extends Controller {

    /**
     * @Route("/", name="front_index")
     * @Route("/{_locale}/", name="front_index+locale", requirements={"_locale": "\w{2,3}"})
     * @return Response
     */
    public function indexAction() {
        return $this->render('test/domain-translation.html.twig');
    }

}
```

And here's my `RoutingExtension` overload:

```
<?php

// src\AppBundle\Twig\LocaleRoutingExtension.php

namespace AppBundle\Twig;

use AppBundle\Document\Domain;
use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\RoutingExtension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class LocaleRoutingExtension extends RoutingExtension {

    /** @var ContainerInterface */
    protected $container;

    /** @var Domain */
    protected $domain;

    /** @var Request */
    protected $request;

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container) {
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->domain = $this->container->get('app.domain_service')->getDomain();
        $this->request = $this->container->get('request_stack')->getMasterRequest();
    }

    protected function processNameAndParameters($name, $parameters) {

        $nameWithLocale = $name . '+locale';
        $routes = $this->container->get('router')->getRouteCollection();
        $route = $routes->get($nameWithLocale);

        if (array_key_exists('no-locale-filter', $parameters) && $parameters['no-locale-filter']) {
            unset($parameters['no-locale-filter']);
            return array('name' => $name, 'parameters' => $parameters);
        }

        if (isset($this->domain) && $this->domain->hasMultipleLocales() && isset($route)) {
            $name = $nameWithLocale;

            $locale = null;
            if (!array_key_exists('_locale', $parameters)) {
                if (isset($this->request)) {
                    $locale = $this->request->getLocale();
                } else {
                    $locale = $this->domain->getDefaultLocale();
                }
            }

            $parameters['_locale'] = $locale;
        }

        return array('name' => $name, 'parameters' => $parameters);
    }

    public function getPath($name, $parameters = array(), $relative = false) {
        $processed = $this->processNameAndParameters($name, $parameters);
        return parent::getPath($processed['name'], $processed['parameters'], $relative);
    }

    public function getUrl($name, $parameters = array(), $schemeRelative = false) {
        $processed = $this->processNameAndParameters($name, $parameters);
        return parent::getUrl($processed['name'], $processed['parameters'], $schemeRelative);
    }

}
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I do this in my project (yml)

```
language_selection:
    path: /{locale}/{path}
    defaults: { _controller: PurchaserBundle:Home:langSelection, path: "" }
    requirements:
        path:  .+
        locale: es|ca|en
```

And in the controller:

```
public function langSelectionAction($locale, $path)
{
    if (in_array($locale, array('es', 'en', 'ca'))) {
        return $this->redirect('/' . $path);
    }

    $this->create404NotFound();
}
```

It is maybe a rudimentary way to solve the problem, but works. All of your "default" routes works, and if you access to the site with any locale prefix, your listener change the language and this controller redirects to the correct route in the current language.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not what I'm looking for, because it uses redirects and forces having a locale in the URL.

Comment: It is not necessary have a locale in the url. This route is defined at the end of my routing file, so only is matched when all other routes are not used

Comment: I understand the user doesn't have to access a URL with a locale in it, but the resulting one (after the redirection) will have one.

Comment: It is just the opposite. The user access to domain.com/es/home (for example) and the result after redirection is domain.com/home with the locale changed to "es"

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to customize the routingComponent by just extending it. This way every url which matches no routes, will be retried prefixing url with default locale

```
<?php

namespace App\Component;

use Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Matcher\UrlMatcher as BaseUrlMatcher;

class UrlMatcher extends BaseUrlMatcher
{
    public function match($pathinfo)
    {
        try {
            return parent::match($pathinfo);
        } catch (ResourceNotFoundException $exception) {
            $url = sprintf('/%s%s', 'en', $pathinfo);

            return parent::match($url);
        }
    }
}
```

Set new urlMatcher in parameters:

```
parameters:
        # UrlMatcher
        router.options.matcher.cache_class: ~
        router.options.matcher_class: App\Component\UrlMatcher
```